# Super resolution with STED microscopy and evanescent waves?

Tags: lenses, microscopy, imaging

Consider the angular spectrum method, given a field $U$ with a wavelength $\lambda$ we can decompose it with Fourier transform.

\begin{equation}
 U(x, y,0) = \int \int  {\tilde{U}_0(f_x,f_y)} e^{2 \pi i (f_x x + f_y y)} d f_x d f_y
\end{equation}

And propagate it along a distance $z$

\begin{equation}
 U(x, y, z) = \int \int   {\tilde{U}_0(f_x,f_y)} e^{2 \pi i (f_x x + f_y y + {z \sqrt{\frac{1}{\lambda^2} - f^2_x - f^2_y}})} d f_x d f_y
\end{equation}

When $\frac{1}{\lambda^2} - f^2_x - f^2_y <0$ I will have evanescent fields

\begin{equation}
 e^{ - 2 \pi { z \sqrt{ \lvert \frac{1}{\lambda^2} - f^2_x - f^2_y}\rvert}}
\end{equation}

so in the far-field (z>>0) I loose all the information connected with high spatial frequencies, i.e. small details, I can not distinguish details smaller than $ \lambda$ approximately.

Stimulated Emission Depletion (STED) microscopy is a technique that, in the field of fluorescent microscopy,  is able to do super resolution in the far field with a combination of a normal beam and a beam with a donut shape. It is able to distinguish details smaller than $\lambda$ around 50 nm, for example, in the visible light.

Why the reasoning of evanescent waves doesn't apply with STED?